# Updating module on instant change when list is updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, vue.js, vuejs2

Sorry for the long post, but I tried explaining things in as much detail as possible.

So as I dive deeper into JavaScript and start learning more and more about AJAX requests and other components, I've stumbled across something that I can't seem to figure out.

So below, I will explain what I'm doing and what I would like to do, and see if someone has some guidance for me.

So here is my `Vue.js` app:

```
new Vue({
    name: 'o365-edit-modal',
    el: '#o365-modal-edit',
    data: function() {
        return {
            list: {},
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.fetchApplicationsMenu();
    },
    methods: {
        fetchApplicationsMenu() {
            var self = this;
            wp.apiRequest( {
                path: 'fh/v1/menus/applications',
                method: 'GET',
            }).then(menu => self.list = menu.data);
        },
        changed() {
            const selected = this.$data.list.selected;
            function get_ids(list, field) {
                const output = [];
                for (let i=0; i < list.length ; ++i)
                    output.push(list[i][field]);
                return output;
            }
            const result = get_ids(selected, "id");
            wp.apiRequest( {
                path: 'fh/v1/menus/applications',
                method: 'PUT',
                data: {
                    ids: result,
                },
            }).then((post) => {
                return post;
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
        add(x) {
            this.$data.list.selected.push(...this.$data.list.available.splice(x, 1));
            this.changed();
        },
        remove(x) {
            this.$data.list.available.push(...this.$data.list.selected.splice(x, 1));
            this.changed();
        },
    },
});
```

Then here is the HTML portion that I'm using to render the two columns:

```html
<div class="column is-half-desktop is-full-mobile buttons">
    <nav class="level is-mobile mb-0">
        <div class="level-left">
            <div class="level-item is-size-5 has-text-left">Selected</div>
        </div>
        <div class="level-right">
            <div class="level-item">
                <i class="fas fa-sort-alpha-up is-clickable"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <hr class="mt-1 mb-3">
    <draggable class="list-group"
               v-model="list.selected"
               v-bind="dragOptions"
               :list="list.selected"
               :move="onMove"
               @change="changed">
        <button class="button is-fullwidth is-flex list-group-item o365_app_handle level is-mobile" v-for="(app, index) in list.selected" :key="app.id">
            <div class="level-left">
                    <span class="icon" aria-hidden="true">
                        <img :src="app.icon_url" />
                    </span>
                <span>{{app.name}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="level-right">
                <span class="icon has-text-danger is-clickable" @click="remove(index)">
                  <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                </span>
            </div>
        </button>
    </draggable>
</div>
<div class="column is-half-desktop is-full-mobile buttons">
    <div class="is-size-5 has-text-left">Available</div>
    <hr class="mt-1 mb-3">
    <draggable class="list-group"
               v-model="list.available"
               v-bind="dragOptions"
               :list="list.available"
               :move="onMove">
        <button class="button is-fullwidth is-flex list-group-item o365_app_handle level is-mobile" v-for="(app, index) in list.available" :key="app.id">
            <div class="level-left">
                <span class="icon" aria-hidden="true">
                    <img :src="app.icon_url" />
                </span>
                <span>{{app.name}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="level-right">
                <span class="icon has-text-primary is-clickable" @click="add(index)">
                  <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                </span>
            </div>
        </button>
    </draggable>
</div>
```

That outputs the following items, and all works great. See the video display below of each component working as needed. This all works great! I'm calling the `changed()` method on add and remove which grabs all the IDs and stores them in the DB via an endpoint.

[image]

---

**The Problem**:

Now I have the following dropdown menu, which depends on the `fh/v1/menus/applications` endpoint to pull in all the items as shown below:

[image]

As you can see below, when I open the dropdown, it has three apps, when I open the cog wheel and remove one of the apps and it saves it but the dropdown doesn't get automatically updated, I have to refresh the page and then I will see the updates.

Does anyone know how to fetch the new items without a refresh?

Here is the HTML and the JS for the dropdown piece:

**HTML**: As you can see in there, I have `data-source="applications"` which pulls in the items inside the `init_menu` as shown in the JS.

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-o365" role="menu">
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <div class="container is-fluid px-4 pb-4">
            <?php if ($application = Applications::init()): ?>
            <div class="columns">
                <div class="dropdown-item column is-full has-text-centered is-size-6">
                    <div class="level is-mobile">
                        <div class="level-left">
                            <?= $application->get_name() ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="level-right">
                            <a class="navbar-item modal-element icon" id="o365-apps-cogwheel" data-target="o365-modal-edit" aria-haspopup="true">
                                <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="columns is-multiline" data-source="applications"></div>
            <?php else: ?>
            <div class="columns">
                <div class="column is-full">
                    No applications present.
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then here is the JavaScript. I initilize the method inside `DOMContentLoaded` using `init_menu('applications');`:

```
function init_menu(paths)
{
    paths.forEach(path => {
        const target = document.querySelector('[data-source=' + path + ']');
        if (target) {
            wp.api.loadPromise.done(function () {
                const Menus = wp.api.models.Post.extend({
                    url: wpApiSettings.root + 'fh/v1/menus/' + path,
                });
                const menus = new Menus();
                menus.fetch().then(posts => {

                    // This returns the data object.
                    const data = posts.data;
                    let post_list;

                    // Check if it's an array and see if selected is empty otherwise show available.
                    if (Array.isArray(data.selected) && data.selected.length !== 0) {
                        post_list = data.selected;
                    } else {
                        post_list = data.available;
                    }
                    post_list.forEach(function (post) {
                        switch(path) {
                            case 'applications':
                                target.appendChild(create_apps_dom_tree(post));
                                break;
                            default:
                                console.log('Path route is invalid.');
                                break;
                        }
                    })
                })
            })
        }
    });
}

function create_apps_dom_tree(post) {
    const {
        icon_url,
        url,
        name,
    } = post
    const container = document.createElement('div');
    container.className = 'column is-one-third is-flex py-0';
    const anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.href = url;
    anchor.className = 'dropdown-item px-2 is-flex is-align-items-center';
    const figure = document.createElement('figure');
    figure.className = 'image is-32x32 is-flex';
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = icon_url;
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    span.className = 'pl-2';
    span.textContent = name;
    figure.appendChild(img);
    anchor.append(figure, span);
    container.appendChild(anchor);
    return container;
}
```

If anyone has some guidance or an answer on how to pull in live data from the database on the fly, that would be amazing.

**Basically, I need my `data-source:` to automatically grab the items when my vue/db request is sent so I don't have to refresh the page.**

Inside my Vue app, I have the following method:

```
fetchApplicationsMenu() {
    var self = this;
    wp.apiRequest( {
        path: 'fh/v1/menus/applications',
        method: 'GET',
    }).then(menu => self.list = menu.data);
},
```

which calls a GET request and then stores the data inside the `return { list: {} }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix might be to just invoke `init_menu()` from the component's [`beforeDestroy()` hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeDestroy), called when the dialog closes. You might choose to do it from `changed()` instead if the dropdown is still accessible with this dialog open.

```js
new Vue({
  // option 1:
  beforeDestroy() {
    init_menu('applications');
  },

  // option 2:
  methods: {
    changed() {
      init_menu('applications');
    }
  }
})
```

**Alternative:** You already know what the final application list is in `changed()`, so you could update the dropdown with the new list from that method.

```js
function update_menu(path, post_list) {
  const target = document.querySelector('[data-source=' + path + ']');

  // remove all existing children
  Array.from(target.childNodes).forEach(x => x.remove());

  post_list.forEach(post => target.appendChild(create_apps_dom_tree(post)))
}

new Vue({
  methods: {
    changed() {
      update_menu('applications', this.$data.available);
    }
  }
})
```